# How can I make my Sass Mixin DRY-er?

Tags: css, sass

I have created several mixins for all buttons to attempt to reduce duplication and contribute to the overall improvement of performance. I am looking for guidance on how to tighten this up so it is as DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) as possible. Or is it already as DRY as possible? Thank you very much for your thoughts. Here is the code:

```
// mixin - button shape
@mixin buttonShape {
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:1.333rem;height:2.166rem;
    color:#282a2e;
    border-radius:0;
    margin-top:1.083rem;
    margin-bottom:.333rem;
    margin-right:1.073rem;
    border:none;
    transition: background-color .2s;
}

// mixin - button gradients
@mixin gradientNormal {
    background-color:#efefee;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#efefee 0,#d0d0ce 100%);
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 .083rem #fff;outline:1px solid silver;
}

@mixin gradientHoverActive {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#ffffff 0,#ffffff 100%);
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 .083rem #fff;outline:2px solid #e87722;
}


// normal state
.ui-widget-header .ui-button, .ui-widget-content .ui-button, .ui-button {
    font-size: 12px;
    @include buttonShape;
    @include gradientNormal;
}

// hover
.ui-widget-header .ui-button:enabled:hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-button:focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-button:enabled:hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-button:focus,
.ui-button:enabled:hover, .ui-button:focus {
    @include buttonShape;
    @include gradientHoverActive;
}

// active
.ui-widget-header .ui-button:enabled:active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-button:enabled:active,
.ui-button:enabled:active {
    @include buttonShape;
    @include gradientHoverActive;
}
```

Comment: This would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/   --- side-note / nothing you do will improve performance by any humanly perceivable measures. `.ui-widget-header` could go... the buttons don't need to be so qualified

Comment: Thank you sheriffderek I'll head over to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

First, your `font-size: 12px` is only referenced by selectors that include `gradientNormal`, so it makes sense to move it to there.

You can also combine your `active` and `hover` states into one, as they have exactly the same includes:

```
// mixin - button shape
@mixin buttonShape {
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height:1.333rem;
    height:2.166rem;
    color:#282a2e;
    border-radius:0;
    margin-top:1.083rem;
    margin-bottom:.333rem;
    margin-right:1.073rem;
    border:none;
    transition: background-color .2s;
}

// mixin - button gradients
@mixin gradientNormal {
    background-color:#efefee;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#efefee 0,#d0d0ce 100%);
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 .083rem #fff;
    outline:1px solid silver;
    font-size: 12px;
}

@mixin gradientHoverActive {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom,#ffffff 0,#ffffff 100%);
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 .083rem #fff;
    outline:2px solid #e87722;
}

// normal state
.ui-widget-header .ui-button, .ui-widget-content .ui-button, .ui-button {
    @include buttonShape;
    @include gradientNormal;
}

// hover & active
.ui-widget-header .ui-button:enabled:hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-button:focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-button:enabled:hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-button:focus,
.ui-button:enabled:hover, .ui-button:focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-button:enabled:active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-button:enabled:active,
.ui-button:enabled:active {
    @include buttonShape;
    @include gradientHoverActive;
}
```

You could also separate out selectors based on which gradient they use, considering `@include buttonShape` is referenced by all three states, though that would result in a larger total number of lines.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see you HTML, but I think that this can be further simplified in the cascading realm - more than the SCSS

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/qyz3tye3/

```
<button class='button'>
  <span>Button</span>
</button>



<section class="other-area">

  <div class='button'>
    <span>Button</span>
  </div>

</section>
```

...

```
/* https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements, but allowing components to change */
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}


$color: lightgreen;
$pad: 6px;

@mixin button() {
  // some reset stuff for <button> and <a>
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  // actual styles
  display: inline-block;
  background: $color;
  padding: $pad;
  border-radius: $pad;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
}

@mixin strong-button() {
  padding: $pad*2 $pad*3;
  background: lightblue;
  max-width: 200px;
}

@mixin fun-button() {
  background: #ff0066;
  color: white;
}

.button {
  @include button();
}

.other-area {
  //
  .button {
    @include fun-button();
  }
}

.another-area {
  //
  .button {
    @include strong-button();
  }
}
```